# How to make a shadow for UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I need to make a shadow for CollectionViewCell. I added a view to the collectionview cell but couldn't make a proper shadow like this : [shadow and radius which i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P51Ka.png) , here's my shadow [my radius and shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDcmZ.png)

Here's a code a wrote: `

```
    let gray = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    viewCollectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    viewCollectionView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
    viewCollectionView.layer.borderColor = gray
    
    viewCollectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 100.0
    viewCollectionView.layer.shadowColor = gray
    viewCollectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    viewCollectionView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    viewCollectionView.clipsToBounds = false`
```

Comment: Add the shadow to the cells, not the collection view.

Comment: I added it to the view in the collection view cell file, it's not right?

Comment: Is `viewCollectionView` an instance of `UICollectionView` or `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: It's an instance of UICOllectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

One way to get that "shadow effect" is to add a "rounded corners" view to the cell's content view, add your imageView and labels to that rounded corners view, and then add the shadow properties to the rounded corners view.

You'll want to inset the rounded corners view enough so that your shadows aren't clipped by the cell itself.

So, look at this cell class:

```
class ShadowedCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let roundedCornerView = UIView()

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let labelA = UILabel()
    let labelB = UILabel()
    let labelC = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        roundedCornerView.backgroundColor = .white
        roundedCornerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(roundedCornerView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            roundedCornerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            roundedCornerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            roundedCornerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            roundedCornerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
        
        roundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        
        roundedCornerView.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
        roundedCornerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        roundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        roundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 4.0)
        
        // add labels, imageView, etc to roundedView
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        roundedCornerView.addSubview(imageView)
        roundedCornerView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: roundedCornerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),

        ])

        labelA.textAlignment = .center
        labelB.textAlignment = .center
        labelC.textAlignment = .center

        labelA.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
        labelB.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
        labelC.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)

        labelB.textColor = .gray
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(labelA)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(labelB)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(labelC)

    }
    
}
```

and example view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var cvCurWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
        // cell width will be set in viewDidLayoutSubviews
        fl.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 250)
        
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(ShadowedCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if cvCurWidth != collectionView.frame.width {
            cvCurWidth = collectionView.frame.width
            if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                fl.itemSize.width = (collectionView.frame.width - fl.minimumInteritemSpacing) * 0.5
                collectionView.collectionViewLayout = fl
            }
        }
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! ShadowedCollectionViewCell
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "cvPic") {
            c.imageView.image = img
        }
        c.labelA.text = "LabelA: \(indexPath.item)"
        c.labelB.text = "LabelB: \(indexPath.item)"
        c.labelC.text = "LabelC: \(indexPath.item)"
        
        return c
    }
    
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]